# Send email to a partner from create method Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I trying to send an email to a partner while create a document. The message is creates but not sending to **SOME** partner. Below is my code.

I configured partners with valid email address.

***.py**

```py
@api.model
def create(self,vals):
    result = super(HRHolidays,self).create(vals)
    message_sent = result.message_post(message_type='notification', subtype='mt_comment', partner_ids=[25])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can send a mail using create method.

```
@api.model
def create(self,vals):
    #Your code
    #some code

    object_id = super(YourClassName, self).create(vals)
    if object_id:
        template_id = self.env.ref('YourModuleName.your_mail_template_id')
    if template_id:
        template_id.send_mail(object_id.id, force_send=True) 
    return res
```

Comment: Thanks Sfx for reply. I tried you method. Result is same. The both above code are working fine. But some partners won't send mail. i don't know why?. configured partners with correct email address.